# Laravel Password Confirmation Return ValidationException

Tags: php, laravel

if i delete the password validation this work fine

```
request()->validate([
        'nombre'=>'required|string|min:5|max:255',
        'correo' =>'email',    
        'password' => ['required','string','min:8','regex:/[a-z]/','regex:/[A-Z]/','regex:/[0-9]/'],          
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
        'rol'=>'required'
      ]);
```

This return

```
[2020-11-06 16:46:54] local.INFO: Error: Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid. in C:\laragon\www\luzatuvida\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:452
```

Comment: Sidenote, putting a restriction on password like that, where you only allow `0-9`, `a-z` and `A-Z` is encouraging weak passwords... I'd consider removing that regex completely, or modifying it to allow special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `|` as separator, and you can merge the password regex

```
   'password' => 'required|string|min:8|regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9]/',
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the array `[ ... ]` if you're using `|` as a separator: `'password' => 'required|string|min:8|regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9]/'`. I think the main issue was the double `regex:` key ; the second would have overridden the first for a partial (aka incorrect) regex

Comment: The problem was the multiple regular expression rules. By making your rules a string, you're just adding an extra step to the validation process as it has to `explode()` them. There's nothing wrong with using an array.